# JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find XML setup file 3.1

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0

I have downloaded this template but I just keep recieving the same error message and I've read you need to edit the xml file but I can't seem to find one that contains the install tag.

This is the template in question.

http://www.joomla24.com/remository/finishdown/5741.html

Comment: you did extract that package before trying to install yes?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you install it as a zip file

Comment: I didn't realise how many zip files were there. Thank you, I just installed them one by one.

Comment: thought that might have been the issue. You should add an answer and accept itt o mark it as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After help I realised there were multiple zip files inside the other zip which needed to be installed individually.